Проблема с установкой autopep8 в Jupyter Notebook
Проблема с установкой autopep8 в Jupyter Notebook, Windows 11.
Хотелось бы получить кнопку с молоточком. Раньше делал получилось, сейчас ни в какую. Инструкция у меня такая:

Как пользоваться библиотекой autopep8?
Шаг 1. Установите jupyter nbextensions, чтобы появилась волшебная
кнопка nbextentions config. Для этого в терминале наберите команду:
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
Шаг 2. Установите autopep8. Для этого в терминале наберите команду:
pip install autopep8
Шаг 3. Откройте Jupyter Notebook -> Edit -> nbextentions config
Шаг 4. Установите галочку напротив нужного пункта.
Шаг 5. На панели инструментов вы увидите новую иконку молотка.

Пишу в Jupyter Notebook:
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - jupyter_contrib_nbextensions


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  autopep8           conda-forge/noarch::autopep8-2.0.4-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  flake8             pkgs/main/win-64::flake8-6.0.0-py311haa95532_0 
  ipython            pkgs/main/win-64::ipython-8.15.0-py311haa95532_0 
  ipywidgets         conda-forge/noarch::ipywidgets-8.0.3-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  jsonpatch          conda-forge/noarch::jsonpatch-1.33-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  jupyter_contrib_c~ conda-forge/noarch::jupyter_contrib_core-0.4.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  jupyter_contrib_n~ conda-forge/noarch::jupyter_contrib_nbextensions-0.7.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  jupyter_highlight~ conda-forge/noarch::jupyter_highlight_selected_word-0.2.0-pyhd8ed1ab_1006 
  jupyter_latex_envs conda-forge/noarch::jupyter_latex_envs-1.4.6-pyhd8ed1ab_1002 
  jupyter_nbextensi~ conda-forge/noarch::jupyter_nbextensions_configurator-0.6.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  jupyterlab_widgets conda-forge/noarch::jupyterlab_widgets-3.0.10-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  packaging          conda-forge/noarch::packaging-24.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  pycodestyle        pkgs/main/win-64::pycodestyle-2.10.0-py311haa95532_0 
  pyflakes           pkgs/main/win-64::pyflakes-3.0.1-py311haa95532_0 
  setuptools         conda-forge/noarch::setuptools-69.5.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  tomli              conda-forge/noarch::tomli-2.0.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0 
  widgetsnbextension conda-forge/noarch::widgetsnbextension-4.0.10-pyhd8ed1ab_0 

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  ca-certificates    pkgs/main::ca-certificates-2023.12.12~ --> conda-forge::ca-certificates-2024.2.2-h56e8100_0 



Downloading and Extracting Packages


Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Verifying transaction: ...working... failed

Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - defaults/win-64::aiobotocore==2.5.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::aiofiles==22.1.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::aiohttp==3.8.5=py311h2bbff1b_0
  - defaults/noarch::aioitertools==0.7.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::aiosignal==1.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::aiosqlite==0.18.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::alabaster==0.7.12=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::anaconda-anon-usage==0.4.2=py311hfc23b7f_0
  - defaults/win-64::anaconda-catalogs==0.2.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::anaconda-client==1.12.1=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::anaconda-cloud-auth==0.1.3=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::anaconda-navigator==2.5.3=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::anaconda-project==0.11.1=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::anyio==3.5.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::appdirs==1.4.4=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::argon2-cffi==21.3.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0=py311h2bbff1b_0
  - defaults/win-64::arrow==1.2.3=py311haa95532_1
  - defaults/win-64::astroid==2.14.2=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::astropy==5.1=py311h5bb9823_0
  - defaults/noarch::asttokens==2.0.5=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::async-timeout==4.0.2=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::atomicwrites==1.4.0=py_0
  - defaults/win-64::attrs==22.1.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::automat==20.2.0=py_0
  - defaults/win-64::babel==2.11.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::backcall==0.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::backports==1.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::backports.functools_lru_cache==1.6.4=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::backports.tempfile==1.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - defaults/noarch::backports.weakref==1.0.post1=py_1
  - defaults/win-64::bcrypt==3.2.0=py311h2bbff1b_1
  - defaults/win-64::beautifulsoup4==4.12.2=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::binaryornot==0.4.4=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - defaults/win-64::black==23.3.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::bleach==4.1.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::bokeh==3.2.1=py311h746a85d_0
  - defaults/win-64::boltons==23.0.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::botocore==1.29.76=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::bottleneck==1.3.5=py311h5bb9823_0
  - defaults/win-64::brotlipy==0.7.0=py311h2bbff1b_1002
  - defaults/win-64::certifi==2024.2.2=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::cffi==1.15.1=py311h2bbff1b_3
  - defaults/win-64::chardet==4.0.0=py311haa95532_1003
  - defaults/noarch::charset-normalizer==2.0.4=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::click==8.0.4=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::cloudpickle==2.2.1=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::clyent==1.2.2=py311haa95532_1
  - defaults/win-64::colorama==0.4.6=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::colorcet==3.0.1=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::comm==0.1.2=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::conda==23.7.4=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::conda-build==3.26.1=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::conda-content-trust==0.2.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::conda-index==0.3.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::conda-libmamba-solver==23.7.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::conda-pack==0.6.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::conda-package-handling==2.2.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::conda-package-streaming==0.9.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::conda-repo-cli==1.0.75=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::conda-token==0.4.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::conda-verify==3.4.2=py_1
  - defaults/win-64::console_shortcut==0.1.1=4
  - defaults/win-64::constantly==15.1.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::contourpy==1.0.5=py311h59b6b97_0
  - defaults/noarch::cookiecutter==1.7.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::cryptography==41.0.3=py311h89fc84f_0
  - defaults/noarch::cssselect==1.1.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::cycler==0.11.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::cytoolz==0.12.0=py311h2bbff1b_0
  - defaults/win-64::daal4py==2023.1.1=py311h30df693_0
  - defaults/win-64::dask==2023.6.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::dask-core==2023.6.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::datasets==2.12.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::datashader==0.15.2=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::datashape==0.5.4=py311haa95532_1
  - defaults/win-64::debugpy==1.6.7=py311hd77b12b_0
  - defaults/noarch::decorator==5.1.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::defusedxml==0.7.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::diff-match-patch==20200713=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::dill==0.3.6=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::distributed==2023.6.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::docstring-to-markdown==0.11=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::docutils==0.18.1=py311haa95532_3
  - defaults/win-64::entrypoints==0.4=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::et_xmlfile==1.1.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::executing==0.8.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::filelock==3.9.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::flask==2.2.2=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::fonttools==4.25.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::frozenlist==1.3.3=py311h2bbff1b_0
  - defaults/win-64::fsspec==2023.4.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::future==0.18.3=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::gensim==4.3.0=py311heda8569_0
  - defaults/noarch::glob2==0.7=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::greenlet==2.0.1=py311hd77b12b_0
  - defaults/win-64::h5py==3.9.0=py311h4e0e482_0
  - defaults/noarch::heapdict==1.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::holoviews==1.17.1=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::huggingface_hub==0.15.1=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::hvplot==0.8.4=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::hyperlink==21.0.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::idna==3.4=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::imagecodecs==2023.1.23=py311he6ff3c7_0
  - defaults/win-64::imageio==2.26.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::imagesize==1.4.1=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::imbalanced-learn==0.10.1=py311haa95532_1
  - defaults/win-64::importlib-metadata==6.0.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::importlib_metadata==6.0.0=hd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::incremental==21.3.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::inflection==0.5.1=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::iniconfig==1.1.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::intake==0.6.8=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::intervaltree==3.1.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::ipykernel==6.25.0=py311h746a85d_0
  - defaults/noarch::ipython_genutils==0.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - defaults/noarch::isort==5.9.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::itemadapter==0.3.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::itemloaders==1.0.4=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - defaults/noarch::itsdangerous==2.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::jaraco.classes==3.2.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::jedi==0.18.1=py311haa95532_1
  - defaults/win-64::jellyfish==1.0.1=py311h36a85e1_0
  - defaults/win-64::jinja2==3.1.2=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::jinja2-time==0.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_3
  - defaults/noarch::jmespath==0.10.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::joblib==1.2.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::json5==0.9.6=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::jsonpointer==2.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::jsonschema==4.17.3=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::jupyter==1.0.0=py311haa95532_8
  - defaults/win-64::jupyterlab==3.6.3=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::jupyterlab_pygments==0.1.2=py_0
  - defaults/win-64::jupyterlab_server==2.22.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::jupyter_client==7.4.9=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::jupyter_console==6.6.3=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::jupyter_core==5.3.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::jupyter_events==0.6.3=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::jupyter_server==1.23.4=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::jupyter_server_fileid==0.9.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::jupyter_server_ydoc==0.8.0=py311haa95532_1
  - defaults/win-64::jupyter_ydoc==0.2.4=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::keyring==23.13.1=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::kiwisolver==1.4.4=py311hd77b12b_0
  - defaults/win-64::lazy-object-proxy==1.6.0=py311h2bbff1b_0
  - defaults/win-64::lazy_loader==0.2=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::libmambapy==1.5.1=py311h77c03ed_0
  - defaults/win-64::linkify-it-py==2.0.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::llvmlite==0.40.0=py311hf2fb9eb_0
  - defaults/win-64::locket==1.0.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::lxml==4.9.3=py311h09808a7_0
  - defaults/win-64::lz4==4.3.2=py311h2bbff1b_0
  - defaults/win-64::markdown==3.4.1=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::markdown-it-py==2.2.0=py311haa95532_1
  - defaults/win-64::markupsafe==2.1.1=py311h2bbff1b_0
  - defaults/win-64::matplotlib==3.7.2=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::matplotlib-base==3.7.2=py311hf62ec03_0
  - defaults/win-64::matplotlib-inline==0.1.6=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::mccabe==0.7.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::mdit-py-plugins==0.3.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::mdurl==0.1.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::menuinst==1.4.19=py311h59b6b97_1
  - defaults/win-64::mistune==0.8.4=py311h2bbff1b_1000
  - defaults/win-64::mkl-service==2.4.0=py311h2bbff1b_1
  - defaults/win-64::mkl_fft==1.3.8=py311h2bbff1b_0
  - defaults/win-64::mkl_random==1.2.4=py311h59b6b97_0
  - defaults/noarch::more-itertools==8.12.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::mpmath==1.3.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::msgpack-python==1.0.3=py311h59b6b97_0
  - defaults/win-64::multidict==6.0.2=py311h2bbff1b_0
  - defaults/win-64::multipledispatch==0.6.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::multiprocess==0.70.14=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::munkres==1.1.4=py_0
  - defaults/win-64::mypy_extensions==1.0.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::navigator-updater==0.4.0=py311haa95532_1
  - defaults/win-64::nbclassic==0.5.5=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::nbclient==0.5.13=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::nbconvert==6.5.4=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::nbformat==5.9.2=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::nest-asyncio==1.5.6=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::networkx==3.1=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::nltk==3.8.1=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::notebook==6.5.4=py311haa95532_1
  - defaults/win-64::notebook-shim==0.2.2=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::numba==0.57.1=py311hf62ec03_0
  - defaults/win-64::numexpr==2.8.4=py311h1fcbade_1
  - defaults/win-64::numpy==1.24.3=py311hdab7c0b_1
  - defaults/win-64::numpy-base==1.24.3=py311hd01c5d8_1
  - defaults/win-64::numpydoc==1.5.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::openpyxl==3.0.10=py311h2bbff1b_0
  - defaults/win-64::pandas==2.0.3=py311hf62ec03_0
  - defaults/noarch::pandocfilters==1.5.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::panel==1.2.3=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::param==1.13.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::paramiko==2.8.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::parsel==1.6.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::parso==0.8.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::partd==1.4.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::pathlib==1.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - defaults/win-64::pathspec==0.10.3=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::patsy==0.5.3=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::pep8==1.7.1=py311haa95532_1
  - defaults/noarch::pexpect==4.8.0=pyhd3eb1b0_3
  - defaults/noarch::pickleshare==0.7.5=pyhd3eb1b0_1003
  - defaults/win-64::pillow==10.2.0=py311h2bbff1b_0
  - defaults/win-64::pip==23.2.1=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::pkce==1.0.3=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::pkginfo==1.9.6=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::platformdirs==3.10.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::plotly==5.9.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::pluggy==1.0.0=py311haa95532_1
  - defaults/win-64::ply==3.11=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::powershell_shortcut==0.0.1=3
  - defaults/noarch::poyo==0.5.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::prometheus_client==0.14.1=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::prompt-toolkit==3.0.36=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::prompt_toolkit==3.0.36=hd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::protego==0.1.16=py_0
  - defaults/win-64::psutil==5.9.0=py311h2bbff1b_0
  - defaults/noarch::ptyprocess==0.7.0=pyhd3eb1b0_2
  - defaults/noarch::pure_eval==0.2.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::py-cpuinfo==8.0.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - defaults/win-64::py-lief==0.12.3=py311hd77b12b_0
  - defaults/win-64::pyarrow==11.0.0=py311h8a3a540_1
  - defaults/noarch::pyasn1==0.4.8=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::pyasn1-modules==0.2.8=py_0
  - defaults/win-64::pycosat==0.6.4=py311h2bbff1b_0
  - defaults/noarch::pycparser==2.21=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::pyct==0.5.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::pycurl==7.45.2=py311he2ea4bf_1
  - defaults/win-64::pydantic==1.10.8=py311h2bbff1b_0
  - defaults/win-64::pydispatcher==2.0.5=py311haa95532_2
  - defaults/win-64::pydocstyle==6.3.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::pyerfa==2.0.0=py311h2bbff1b_0
  - defaults/win-64::pygments==2.15.1=py311haa95532_1
  - defaults/win-64::pyjwt==2.4.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::pylint==2.16.2=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::pylint-venv==2.3.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::pyls-spyder==0.4.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::pynacl==1.5.0=py311h8cc25b3_0
  - defaults/win-64::pyodbc==4.0.34=py311hd77b12b_0
  - defaults/win-64::pyopenssl==23.2.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::pyparsing==3.0.9=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::pyqt==5.15.7=py311hd77b12b_0
  - defaults/win-64::pyqt5-sip==12.11.0=py311hd77b12b_0
  - defaults/win-64::pyqtwebengine==5.15.7=py311hd77b12b_0
  - defaults/win-64::pyrsistent==0.18.0=py311h2bbff1b_0
  - defaults/win-64::pysocks==1.7.1=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::pytables==3.8.0=py311h4671533_3
  - defaults/win-64::pytest==7.4.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::python==3.11.5=he1021f5_0
  - defaults/noarch::python-dateutil==2.8.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::python-dotenv==0.21.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::python-fastjsonschema==2.16.2=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::python-json-logger==2.0.7=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::python-kaleido==0.2.1=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::python-libarchive-c==2.9=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - defaults/win-64::python-lmdb==1.4.1=py311hd77b12b_0
  - defaults/win-64::python-lsp-black==1.2.1=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::python-lsp-jsonrpc==1.0.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::python-lsp-server==1.7.2=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::python-slugify==5.0.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::python-snappy==0.6.1=py311hd77b12b_0
  - defaults/noarch::python-tzdata==2023.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::python-xxhash==2.0.2=py311h2bbff1b_1
  - defaults/win-64::pytoolconfig==1.2.5=py311haa95532_1
  - defaults/win-64::pytz==2023.3.post1=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::pyviz_comms==2.3.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::pywavelets==1.4.1=py311h2bbff1b_0
  - defaults/win-64::pywin32==305=py311h2bbff1b_0
  - defaults/win-64::pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0=py311haa95532_1000
  - defaults/win-64::pywinpty==2.0.10=py311h5da7b33_0
  - defaults/win-64::pyyaml==6.0=py311h2bbff1b_1
  - defaults/win-64::pyzmq==23.2.0=py311hd77b12b_0
  - defaults/noarch::qdarkstyle==3.0.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::qstylizer==0.2.2=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::qtawesome==1.2.2=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::qtconsole==5.4.2=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::qtpy==2.2.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::queuelib==1.5.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::regex==2022.7.9=py311h2bbff1b_0
  - defaults/win-64::requests==2.31.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::requests-file==1.5.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::requests-toolbelt==1.0.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::responses==0.13.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::rfc3339-validator==0.1.4=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::rfc3986-validator==0.1.1=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::rope==1.7.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::rtree==1.0.1=py311h2eaa2aa_0
  - defaults/win-64::ruamel.yaml==0.17.21=py311h2bbff1b_0
  - defaults/win-64::ruamel_yaml==0.17.21=py311h2bbff1b_0
  - defaults/win-64::s3fs==2023.4.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::safetensors==0.3.2=py311h062c2fa_0
  - defaults/win-64::scikit-image==0.20.0=py311h3513d60_0
  - defaults/win-64::scikit-learn==1.3.0=py311hf62ec03_0
  - defaults/win-64::scikit-learn-intelex==2023.1.1=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::scipy==1.11.1=py311hc1ccb85_0
  - defaults/win-64::scrapy==2.8.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::seaborn==0.12.2=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::send2trash==1.8.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - defaults/noarch::service_identity==18.1.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - defaults/win-64::sip==6.6.2=py311hd77b12b_0
  - defaults/noarch::six==1.16.0=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - defaults/win-64::smart_open==5.2.1=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::sniffio==1.2.0=py311haa95532_1
  - defaults/noarch::snowballstemmer==2.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::sortedcontainers==2.4.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::soupsieve==2.4=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::sphinx==5.0.2=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::sphinxcontrib-applehelp==1.0.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::sphinxcontrib-devhelp==1.0.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp==2.0.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::sphinxcontrib-jsmath==1.0.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::sphinxcontrib-qthelp==1.0.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml==1.1.5=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::spyder==5.4.3=py311haa95532_1
  - defaults/win-64::spyder-kernels==2.4.4=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::sqlalchemy==1.4.39=py311h2bbff1b_0
  - defaults/noarch::stack_data==0.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::statsmodels==0.14.0=py311hd7041d2_0
  - defaults/win-64::sympy==1.11.1=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::tabulate==0.8.10=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::tbb4py==2021.8.0=py311h59b6b97_0
  - defaults/noarch::tblib==1.7.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::tenacity==8.2.2=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::terminado==0.17.1=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::text-unidecode==1.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::textdistance==4.2.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/noarch::threadpoolctl==2.2.0=pyh0d69192_0
  - defaults/noarch::three-merge==0.1.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::tifffile==2023.4.12=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::tinycss2==1.2.1=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::tldextract==3.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::tokenizers==0.13.2=py311h49fca51_1
  - defaults/noarch::toml==0.10.2=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::tomlkit==0.11.1=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::toolz==0.12.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::tornado==6.3.2=py311h2bbff1b_0
  - defaults/win-64::tqdm==4.65.0=py311h746a85d_0
  - defaults/win-64::traitlets==5.7.1=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::transformers==4.32.1=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::twisted==22.10.0=py311h2bbff1b_0
  - defaults/win-64::twisted-iocpsupport==1.0.2=py311h2bbff1b_0
  - defaults/win-64::typing-extensions==4.7.1=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::typing_extensions==4.7.1=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::uc-micro-py==1.0.1=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::ujson==5.4.0=py311hd77b12b_0
  - defaults/noarch::unidecode==1.2.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::urllib3==1.26.16=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::w3lib==1.21.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::watchdog==2.1.6=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/noarch::wcwidth==0.2.5=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::webencodings==0.5.1=py311haa95532_1
  - defaults/win-64::websocket-client==0.58.0=py311haa95532_4
  - defaults/win-64::werkzeug==2.2.3=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::whatthepatch==1.0.2=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::wheel==0.38.4=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::win_inet_pton==1.1.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::wrapt==1.14.1=py311h2bbff1b_0
  - defaults/win-64::xarray==2023.6.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::xlwings==0.29.1=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::xyzservices==2022.9.0=py311haa95532_1
  - defaults/win-64::y-py==0.5.9=py311hb6bf4ef_0
  - defaults/noarch::yapf==0.31.0=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - defaults/win-64::yarl==1.8.1=py311h2bbff1b_0
  - defaults/win-64::ypy-websocket==0.8.2=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::zict==2.2.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::zipp==3.11.0=py311haa95532_0
  - defaults/win-64::zope==1.0=py311haa95532_1
  - defaults/win-64::zope.interface==5.4.0=py311h2bbff1b_0
  - defaults/win-64::zstandard==0.19.0=py311h2bbff1b_0
  - defaults/win-64::_anaconda_depends==2023.09=py311_mkl_1


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 23.7.4
  latest version: 24.3.0

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda

Or to minimize the number of packages updated during conda update use

     conda install conda=24.3.0



RemoveError: 'jsonpatch' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from
conda's operating environment.
RemoveError: 'packaging' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from
conda's operating environment.
RemoveError: 'setuptools' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from
conda's operating environment.

Потом:
pip install autopep8

Requirement already satisfied: autopep8 in c:\users\lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycodestyle>=2.11.0 in c:\users\lenovo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from autopep8) (2.11.1)
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

И ноутбук перезагружал, и ядро перезапускал, никаких пунктов меню с nbextentions не появляется. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не правильно.

По идее команды нужно в Anaconda prompt делать, а где вы делаете что-то непонятно.

Вот, кстати, сейчас проверю. Я делаю в Jupyter Notebook.

Где именно в нём вы делаете?

В ячейках кода.

Ввел то же самое в Powershell Prompt из Anaconda. По прежнему пока никакого эффекта.

Понятно. Ну в общем я лично от Anaconda отказался, перешёл на Mamba, потому что Anaconda периодически ломалась так, что её с нуля приходилось переставлять, ну и другие проблемы были.

На старом компьютере ссылка из меню на nbextension открывается по ссылке http://localhost:8888/nbextensions/?nbextension=zenmode/main На ноутбуке, что пытаюсь установить сейчас autopep8 эта же ссылка не открывается. Вернее открывается, но пишет 404 : Not Found You are requesting a page that does not exist!
